# Saving an image as jpg gives me plain black

Tags: python, opencv

I am implementing gabor kernels, when I display the kernels while running the code (before saving them) they give me a picture like this

[image]

But after saving the kernels as jpg images using cv2.imwrite, I get like that

[image]

Any explanations? and how to save the kernels as in the first image?

Comment: How are you exactly displaying the first picture? Are you using plt.imshow?

Comment: Once share the code snippet I think it has to do with normalization and type of img data like int16 or float

Comment: Your image may be float values between 0 and 1. Pyplot color codes that for display. But when saved to JPG, it wants range 0 to 255. So all the values are either 0 or 1 in range 0 to 255. So that is black. Multiply your image by 255. Clip to the range 0 to 255 and convert to uint8. Then save as JPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be different causes. So I have two suggestions:

1. If you display the first picture with plt.imshow(), export it with plt.savefig(). This should easily be working.
2. If you still want to export the image with cv2.imwrite() make sure that the picture is correctly rescaled first. (mind that if you have only one channel, you will get a grayscale picture).

If we call the original picture *org_img*:

```
img = org_img
min_val,max_val=img.min(),img.max()
img = 255.0*(img - min_val)/(max_val - min_val)
img = img.astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite(img,"picture.png")
```

Comment: Thanks you so  much, I tried suggestion 1 and it worked.

Comment: I have one more question. Now I am saving the gabor kernels and the gabor filtered images produced using plt.savefig. I am saving them in different folders but I found the gabor kernel images in both of the folders if I am using plt.imshow(kernel) before the saving step, and see the filtered images in both folders if I am using plt.imshow (filtered_img) before the saving step. Any suggestions for that?